# Topology given by a relation

Tags: general-topology, relations, quotient-spaces

I have a problem with creating an equivalence relation ~ in a set :

$ S^{1}\times S^{2}$ so that $ (S^{1}\times S^{2})/$~ (a quotient space of the given relation) is homeomorphic to 3-dimensional sphere.Thank you for any clues.

Comment: By 3-dimensional sphere you mean $S^3$?

Comment: Yes, I do.I know how to prove that it's homeomorphic once I come up with a  relation.I just struggle to find the right one.

Comment: You could think about it in terms of 4D spherical coordinates where $S^2$ holds the "angle" along the equator and $S^1$ holds the other angle.

Comment: You could first solve the problem with $S^1 × S^1 / ~ = S^2$ as that only requires standard 3D spherical coordinates. And when you understand that problem - work from there.

Comment: I would probably start with $[0,1]\times [0,1]^2=[0,1]^3$, and make the spheres from there (both $S^1\times S^2$ and $S^3$) by the standard "collapse the boundary to a point"-construction. Then see that $S^1\times S^2$ may be seen as an intermediate step towards $S^3$.

Comment: That indeed looks way nicer to me than my suggestion. :D